# How to maintain Polars DataFrame metadata through processing, serialization and deserialization in Apache Arrow IPC format in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, metadata, python-polars

I would like to be able to track metadata related to a [polars DataFrame](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/data-structures/#dataframe) through processing, serialization, and deserialization using the Apache Arrow IPC format in python-polars. How can this be accomplished?

A common use case for DataFrame metadata is to store data about how the DataFrame was generated or metadata about the data contained within its columns such as the database it was loaded from, the timezone associated or possibly the CRS or coordinates in the DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to subclass the [polars DataFrame](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/concepts/data-structures/#dataframe) as a 'MetaDataFrame'. By adding a SimpleNamespace as an attribute 'meta' the capability of storing metadata using dot syntax is made available.

As [I answered on polar's issues](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/5117#issuecomment-1924408414), given a MetaDataFrame with metadata, you can add, overwrite and access it through the 'meta' atrribute:

```py
import meta_dataframe as mdf

df = MetaDataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
df.meta.crs = "EPSG:4326"
df.meta.crs = "EPSG:3857"
print(df.meta.crs)

>>> EPSG:3857
```

Additionally, by leveraging the Arrow IPC specification you can provide additional functions to write and read the DataFrame that maintain the metadata through a serialization roundtrip.

```py
filepath = f"{df.meta.name}.ipc"  # use a fully qualified path if desired
df.write_ipc_with_meta(filepath)
loaded_df = mdf.read_ipc_with_meta(filepath)
print(loaded_df.meta.crs)

>>> EPSG:3857
```

##### meta_dataframe Module

```py
# meta_dataframe.py
"""Provides functionality for handling Polars DataFrames with custom metadata.

This module enables the serialization and deserialization of Polars DataFrames
along with associated metadata, utilizing the IPC format for data interchange
and `orjson` for fast JSON processing. Metadata management is facilitated through
the use of the `DfMeta` class, a flexible container for arbitrary metadata fields.
Key functions include `write_ipc_with_meta` and `read_ipc_with_meta`, which allow
for the persistence of metadata across storage cycles, enhancing data context
retention and utility in analytical workflows.

Note:
    This module was not written for efficiency or performance, but to solve the
    use case of persisting metadata with Polars DataFrames. It is not recommended for
    production use, but rather as a starting point for more robust metadata management.

Classes:
    DfMeta: A simple namespace for metadata management.
    MetaDataFrame: An extension of Polars DataFrame to include metadata.

Functions:
    write_ipc_with_meta(df, filepath, meta): Serialize DataFrame and metadata to IPC.
    read_ipc_with_meta(filepath): Deserialize DataFrame and metadata from IPC.
"""


# Standard Library
from typing import Any, Dict
from types import SimpleNamespace

# Third Party
import orjson
import polars as pl
import pyarrow as pa


class DfMeta(SimpleNamespace):
    """A simple namespace for storing MetaDataFrame metadata.

    Usage:
        meta = DfMeta(
        name="checkins",
        db_name="my_db",
        tz_name="America/New_York",
        crs="EPSG:4326"
    )
    """

    # Generate a string representation of metadata keys
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        keys = ", ".join(self.__dict__.keys())
        return f"DfMeta({keys})"

    # Alias __str__ to __repr__ for consistent string representation
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.__repr__()


class MetaDataFrame(pl.DataFrame):
    """A Polars DataFrame extended to include custom metadata.

    Attributes:
        meta (DfMeta): A simple namespace for storing metadata.

    Usage:

        # Create MetaDataFrame with metadata
        meta = DfMeta(
            name="my_df",
            db_name="my_db",
            tz_name="America/New_York",
            crs="EPSG:4326"
        )
        df = MetaDataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]}, meta=meta)

        # Create MetaDataFrame then add metadata
        df = MetaDataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3]})
        df.meta.name = "my_df"
        df.meta.db_name = "my_db"
        df.meta.tz_name = "America/New_York"
        df.meta.crs = "EPSG:4326"

        # Overwrite metadata
        df.meta.crs = "EPSG:3857"

        # Write MetaDataFrame to IPC with metadata
        df.write_ipc_with_meta("my_df.ipc")

        # Read MetaDataFrame from IPC with metadata
        loaded_df = read_ipc_with_meta("my_df.ipc")

        # Access metadata
        print(loaded_df.meta.name)
        print(loaded_df.meta_as_dict())
    """

    # Initialize DataFrame with `meta` attr SimpleNamespace
    def __init__(self, data: Any = None, *args, meta: DfMeta = None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.meta = meta if meta else DfMeta()

    def meta_as_dict(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        """Returns the metadata as a dictionary.

        Returns:
            dict[str, Any]: A dictionary representation of the metadata.
        """
        return vars(self.meta)

    def write_ipc_with_meta(self, filepath: str) -> None:
        """Serialize MetaDataFrame and metadata stored in `meta` attr to an IPC file.

        Args:
            filepath (str): The path to the IPC file.

        Returns:
            None
        """
        # Convert Polars DataFrame to Arrow Table
        arrow_table = self.to_arrow()

        # Serialize metadata to JSON
        meta: DfMeta = self.meta
        meta_dict = {k: v for k, v in meta.__dict__.items()}
        meta_json = orjson.dumps(meta_dict)

        # Embed metadata into Arrow schema
        new_schema = arrow_table.schema.with_metadata({"meta": meta_json})
        arrow_table_with_meta = arrow_table.replace_schema_metadata(new_schema.metadata)

        # Write Arrow table with metadata to IPC file
        with pa.OSFile(filepath, "wb") as sink:
            with pa.RecordBatchStreamWriter(
                sink, arrow_table_with_meta.schema
            ) as writer:
                writer.write_table(arrow_table_with_meta)


def read_ipc_with_meta(filepath: str) -> MetaDataFrame:
    """Deserialize DataFrame and metadata from an IPC file.

    Args:
        filepath (str): The path to the IPC file.

    Returns:
        MetaDataFrame: The deserialized DataFrame with metadata stored in `meta` attr.
    """
    # Read Arrow table from IPC file
    with pa.OSFile(filepath, "rb") as source:
        reader = pa.ipc.open_stream(source)
        table = reader.read_all()

    # Extract and deserialize metadata from Arrow schema
    meta_json = table.schema.metadata.get(b"meta")
    if meta_json:
        meta_dict = orjson.loads(meta_json)
        meta = DfMeta(**meta_dict)
    else:
        meta = DfMeta()

    # Convert Arrow table to Polars DataFrame and attach metadata
    df = pl.from_arrow(table)
    extended_df = MetaDataFrame(df, meta=meta)
    return extended_df
```